# Getting multiple tag-name indexes with JS - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am toying around with W3School's table search function, and was wondering if it is possible to grab multiple getElementsByTagName indexes at once, and thus (in this case) make a search for the entire table instead of just the first index? I have been trying to set up if-statements, but nothing seems to be functioning.

The code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Koniglich Essen</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris specialites</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When changing the index to 1 I am able to search the second row - but what would I do in order to make both searchable simultaneously?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you want to accomplish - the function, as described, hides and shows rows in a table based on whether any of the cells contains the queries. It _is_ searching through all of the rows as far as I can see?

Comment: I think you are trying in fact to keep visible only the `tr` that contain your search string anywhere in it, right ? So maybe just try to match your search string against `innerHTML` from your `tr` element ?

Comment: If I search for Germany no results come up - it only searches in the left column at the moment, trying to make it do in both!

Comment: Your code only looks at the first `<td>` explicitly (that's what `[0]` is doing). You can loop through the `<td>` elements inside the loop for the `<tr>` rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to iterate over your tds, and determine if `some` of the tds contain the searched text:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    // Get all tds in the row.
    const tds = [...tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")]; // Convert the HTMLCollection to Array

    // Check if a td in the row contains a search result.
    const hasSearchResult = tds.some(td => {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      return txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1;
    });

    // 0 length is the header, skip that.
    if (!tds.length || hasSearchResult) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
#myInput { background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); background-position: 10px 10px; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 100%; font-size: 16px; padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; border: 1px solid #ddd; margin-bottom: 12px; }
#myTable { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border: 1px solid #ddd; font-size: 18px; }
#myTable th, #myTable td { text-align: left; padding: 12px; }
#myTable tr { border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; }
#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover { background-color: #f1f1f1; }
```

```html
<h2>My Customers</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td><td>Germany</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Berglunds snabbkop</td><td>Sweden</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Island Trading</td><td>UK</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Koniglich Essen</td><td>Germany</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td><td>Canada</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td><td>Italy</td></tr>
  <tr><td>North/South</td><td>UK</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Paris specialites</td><td>France</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It gives the same result

Comment: @XMehdi01 It certainly does not... Search for something in the 2nd column.

Comment: Yes, well done Good

Comment: Indeed- works like a charm! Cool, and quite another way than I was imagining of doing it. Thanks for the answer!